# How to re-use "component" in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a view for editing address, that has a controller attached to it. It fetches all states and territories, with some internal nomenclature, allows user to select country/state, allows use to enter zip code and it fetches correct city etc. There is also validation, and model that gets populated. It depends on some server side services also. Now, I need to use this exact same functionality in like 5-6 forms. I don't want to copy or repeat logic, I would like to declare it in view as directive, and bind complete model (Address) to model of the enclosing view. How do I do this? How do I make connection between view controller and directive controller, and also how do I make connection between view's model (vm.address) and enclosing model (for example vm.client.address)?

Let's say I have this html snippet that has a controller (addressEditCtrl) associated with it.

```
<div class="row" data-ng-controller="addressEditCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address:</label>
            <span style="margin-left: 10px; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9px;">
                <a href="" style="height: 7px;" data-ng-click="vm.clearAddress()">Clear</a>
            </span>

            <textarea class="form-control" style="height: 80px; width: 300px;"
                      data-ng-model="vm.address.street" maxlength="255"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <label for="zipCode">Zip Code:</label><br>
                <input id="zipCode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" style="float: left; width: 45%; margin-right: 10px;"
                       data-ng-model='vm.address.zipCode'
                       data-ng-blur="vm.bindZipCodeInfo()" maxlength="5">

                <input id="zipCode2" name="zipCode2" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" style="float: left; width: 45%;"
                       data-ng-model='vm.mailingZipPlus' maxlength="4">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=""
                       data-ng-model='vm.address.city' maxlength="30">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-xs-5 p-0">
                <label for="county">County:</label>
                <input id="county" class="col-xs-12" type="text" disabled
                       data-ng-model='vm.address.countyName'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="states">State:</label>
                <select id="states" class="form-control"
                        data-ng-model="vm.address.stateCode"
                        data-ng-options="state.Code as state.Description for state in vm.states">
                    <option value=''> Please Select</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <label for="countries">Country:</label>
                <select id="countries" class="form-control"
                        data-ng-model="vm.selectedCountry"
                        data-ng-options="country as country.Description for country in vm.countries"></select>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to turn this into directive. This piece does not work, because in link function scopes are different (directive vs addressEditorCtrl). I am also not sure if I need link or controller defined on the directive as I am not manipulating anything.

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .directive('srAddressEditor', srAddressEditor);

    srAddressEditor.$inject = [];

    function srAddressEditor() {
        var directive = {
            templateUrl: '/app/shared/addressEditor/addressEdit.html',
            scope: {
                address:'=address'
            }
        };

        return directive;
    }
})(angular);
```

This is what I am after, two way binding.  vm.client.mailingAddress and vm.address in above address editor are of the same shape. Any change in either one of them should be synched. I also want to be able to put multiple of these on the form, so isolated scope is what I am after.

```
<div data-ng-controller="clientEditCtrl">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
            <sr-address-editor address="vm.client.mailingAddress"></sr-address-editor>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has the underpinnings of a good question; so if you can help us by implementing the following, it'll serve to have your question re-opened: 1) Show us a sample of what you have working (actual code); whatever service or controller or directive you have currently should be in your question (in trimmed down form); 2) Reduce your question to the reusing code part, not the extreanous questions after ("How do I do this?") any answer will serve to explain that in its code; and it keeps your question from being taken as too broad.

Comment: I added some sample code with comments that should make it clearer what I am after.